# when weakSelf will be nil in block ,when should add strongSelf

Tags: ios, objective-c

By using weakSelf in the block ,you are avoiding retain cycle.But sometime you should hold weakSelf until block retain ,therefor you need use strongSelf just like

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_group_async(_operationsGroup, _operationsQueue, ^
{
__typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
[strongSelf doSomething];
[strongSelf doSomethingElse];
} );
```

I want know when weakSelf will be nil ,then we should add`__strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf`

Comment: `self` is already strong. You got weak and strong, nothing in between.

Comment: If just use 'self' in block that hold by 'self' , leading to retain cycle .thus you should use weakSelf .StrongSelf is strong reference to self ,but it will be deallocated when block finished.Just by this way don't lead to retain cycle.(just my understand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example: If your aunty asked you, "Please purchase the umbrella from the market before I leave for my flight". You went to the market and it was very hard to find an umbrella. Finally you found a nice umbrella after few hours and you reach home but you find out that your aunt has left and you feel bad. But that was the right thing for your aunt because the flight is more important than the umbrella.

But in your coding problem what you're trying to do is
You are visiting market and taking your aunt's passport with you so that she won't leave until you come back.

I guess that's rude, but if you still want to do that, use `self` instead of `strongSelf`

```
dispatch_group_async(_operationsGroup, _operationsQueue, ^
{
  [self doSomething];
  [self doSomethingElse];
} );
```

Comment: In this case may not use weakSelf . However sometime you need use weakSelf to avid retain cycle. If need use strongSelf to avoid weakSelf deallocated ,then program may be error.

Comment: [My reference](https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/comment-page-1/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog) is right ?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your requirements.  There's no one, right answer.

Capturing `self` weakly allows the instance to be deallocated, even if the block is still retained somewhere.  If `self` is released before the block is executed, it will be `nil` within the block.

If the block should not do anything when `self` has already been deallocated, there is no reason to capture `self` strongly.  Simply test for `nil` and exit early.  Or do whatever work is needed in the block that doesn't act on `self`.

If `self` should not disappear until the block has executed, capture `self` strongly, but avoid retain cycles by ensuring that `self` does not have a strong reference to the block.

If it's OK for `self` to disappear before the block begins executing, but must stick around until the block finishes, the block should capture a strong reference to the weakly-captured `self` when it begins.

Comment: In my case ,'self' must stick around until the block finishes .what situation to use strongSelf or must use strongSelf?

Answer (score 0):

If question is: "when weakSelf will be nil".

The answer is: When no one own the instance of self

For example, you have a `UIViewController` instance named `vc`, `vc` have a dependency for query API named `apiHandler`, and `api` have a callback block named `successCallback`.

like this:

```
@interface ApiHandler: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^successCallback)();

@end



@interface vc : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) ApiHandler *apiHandler;

@end

@implementation vc

- (void)doQuery {
    self.apiHandler.successCallback = ^{
        [self doSomething];
    };
}

- (void)doSomething {

}
```

If `vc` be pop or dismiss, the `vc` instance **WILL NOT BE** dealloc. Because of retain cycle.

`vc` own `apiHandler`, `apiHandler` own `successCallback` and `successCallback` own `vc`.

So, using **weak** `vc` in block can avoid retain cycle.

like this:

```
- (void)doQuery {
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;

    self.apiHandler.successCallback = ^{
        [weakSelf doSomething];
    };
}
```

And now, if your `vc` be pop or dismiss, the `vc` instance will be dealloc, and **weakSelf will be nil**.

When `apiHandler` do query success in background thread and invoke `successCallback`, the message `doSomething` will send to `nil` object. (Zombie)

This is why you need to use strongSelf in block like you said.

Comment: As you said only self be deallocated ,weakSelf will be nil .My understanding is right ?

Comment: @anjingpan, yes, that right. So if you can be sure `self` will not be dealloc, use `self` directly is fine. But be careful about retain cycle.

Comment: @anjingpan, BTW, you can simplify the code by using [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc). Just `@weakify(arg)` and `@strongify(arg)` can do what you want and pretty clear.